# Copy Link Button in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

Is there a service or parameter I am missing to create the "Copy Link" button as seen in Apple's 12 Days app?

I am able to get the Copy button to appear by allowing

```
UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard
```

in my UIActivityViewController, and passing it a URL

```
NSURL *activityURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mylink.com/"];
```

It functions fine, but the button title is "Copy", which is not as clear as "Copy Link". I'm wondering if forcing this title is a service option I've missed, or requires defining a custom activity type. As far as I can tell, activityTitle is only available if you subclass the service method.

Thanks for any insight.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to make your own subclass due to the way the activity view controller's handle displaying options, unfortunately. :\

Comment: Do you have any link or suggestion about **how** or **what** to subclass?

Comment: You subclass UIActivity. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactivity_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Sorry, I was asking about subclassing the _Copy_ activity in particular. Subclassing `UIActivity` I have to duplicate the whole copying-to-the-pasteboard behaviour and the icon selection, when all I want is to just override one of the existing activity's property: it's visible text. Is there a _clean_ way of doing it, or do I have to do it all by hand? Thanks, James :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Unfortunately it's a private class so you'll have to recreate it :/ Here's the private class definition at least: https://github.com/MP0w/iOS-Headers/blob/6e220684809a8e581357c1622efcc002a1df5014/Compare_Latest/Frameworks/UIKit/UICopyToPasteboardActivity.h

Answer (score 5):

I know it is old thread. Here is the answer. Subclass `UIActivity` and copy in pasteboard only of one of the items is `URL` here is the full implementation.

```
private var url = NSURL()

override func activityType() -> String? {
    return "com.productHunt.copyLink"
}

override func activityTitle() -> String? {
    return "Copy Link"
}

override func activityImage() -> UIImage? {
    return UIImage(named: "icon-copy")
}

override func canPerformWithActivityItems(activityItems: [AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    for activityItem in activityItems {
        if let _ = activityItem as? NSURL {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

override func prepareWithActivityItems(activityItems: [AnyObject]) {

    for activityItem in activityItems {
        if let url = activityItem as? NSURL {
            self.url = url
        }
    }
}

override func performActivity() {
    UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = url.absoluteString
    activityDidFinish(true)
}
```